# Displaying a Count text field as zero instead of blank

Tags: count, tableau-api, calculated-columns

I am trying to count unique ID numbers in Tableau; however, when I filter by year, there are some years with no ID numbers. As a result, I want the number 0 to be shown, but instead Tableau just displays a blank. I was trying to use a calculated field like this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
IF(COUNTD([ID]) > 0) THEN COUNTD([ID])
ELSE 0
END
```

Alternatively, I tried this, but it also doesn't work.

```
IF ISNULL(COUNTD([ID])) THEN 0
ELSE COUNTD([ID])
END
```

Here is what the worksheet looks like. It is very simple.

[image]

Filtering out some of the years, you can see how the zero values are simply displayed as blanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZN()function for this.
ZN(CountD[ID]))

Comment: When I filter out a few years, this method still shows a blank value similar to the picture in the original post above @Rizwan Ahmad